# Notion of Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have some difficulties in understanding the notion of distribution.

As I understand, distribution, is some source of data, where each element of the data have some probability to occur, for example in **uniform distribution** the probability to occur of one of the element is $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is the number of elements in the data set.

One of the clearest examples is **geometric distribution**, where probability that *k*'th success is the first success is $Pr(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$, where $p$ is the probability of success.

However, any other distribution is less clear, for example, **Poisson distribution**.

**Definition.** Poisson distribution is a discrete probability distribution that expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time and/or space if these events occur with a known average rate and independently of the time since the last event.

According to the definition here we should have few parameters: interval of time/space, average rate, number of events. I expect that probability mass function will consist of all these parameters, however somehow probability mass function has a form $Pr(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$. According to pmf these is no interval of time/space, however the main question how do we get this pmf, it's less clear than pmf of geometrical distribution.

The same question I can ask about any other distribution, I don't have intuitive understanding behind pmf, some how we just have them without any description. Could you please describe why exactly pmf of Poisson looks like it looks.